# Converting time format in R

Tags: r, datetime, time, format

One of my observation of time data is "Wed Oct 31 13:42:46 2007". 
I want to convert to the format as "2007-10-31 13:42:46" (remove Wed).
How I can convert it?

Comment: See `?strptime` for all the options for `format`-ting Date and POSIX datetime objects. Try: `as.character(as.POSIXct("Wed Oct 31 13:42:46 2007",format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @thelatemail said

```
x <- "Wed Oct 31 13:42:46 2007"
x <- as.POSIXct(x, format = "%a %b %d %T %Y", tz =  "GMT")
# %a day of week, %b month of year, %d day of month as decimal, %T H:M:S, %Y year with century
x
[1] "2007-10-31 13:42:46 GMT"
```